# org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: mysql, jsf, jakarta-ee, payara, netbeans-12

Hi it's my first question here in stack overflow, I have a problem with netbeans 12.5 and jakarta ee, I try to create a simple JSF application, but I got an error that I think it's related to the connection with the DB, knowing that I work with mysql and payara server and that the error is thrown when I try the get all data from the table patient which is already created, That's what the error says:

[screenshot-netbeans-payara-mysql-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0nm1.png)

an here's the stack trace of the error:

```
> javax.ejb.EJBException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Patient sql="SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT")
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:723)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:652)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:482)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2134)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2104)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy495.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at service.__EJB31_Generated__PatientFacade__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at controller.PatientController.getItems(PatientController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:299)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:114)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:177)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:479)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:540)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1153)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1644)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1637)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Patient sql="SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    at service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:588)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:408)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:665)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:834)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:615)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:615)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor512.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4807)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4795)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Patient sql="SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2099)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2759)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2712)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2983)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1544)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:628)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy429.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:609)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:386)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:67)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:1080)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:252)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor400.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.JdbcObjectsFactory$1.invoke(JdbcObjectsFactory.java:143)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PATIENT" non trouvée
Table "PATIENT" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT ID, ADDRESS, NAME FROM PATIENT [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1970)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2827)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2959)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuerySub(Parser.java:2817)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2649)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2620)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:868)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:734)
    ... 130 more
```

here's the content of my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="prod" transaction-type="JTA">
    <class>bean.Patient</class>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="mysql_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" 
  value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and here's my entity:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change 
 this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this 
 template
 */
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
@Entity
public class Patient implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won t work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Patient)) {
            return false;
        }
        Patient other = (Patient) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && 
!this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "bean.Patient[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

please help.

Comment: The error says that your table does not exist. Perhaps you are connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but in the persistence .xml file in the first property its' mentionned that the DB used is: value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", which is the one that contain my table

Comment: Unfortunately, mysql says otherwise and I'm sorry to say, I trust mysql over you.

Comment: ok, I will make sure which DB my App is connected to, thanks